# How to force orientation for some screens in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

With jetpack compose navigation, I suppose it may become a single activity app. How to force orientation only for certain composables (screens)? Say if I want to force landscape only when playing video and not other screens? Without navigation, can declare orientation in manifest but with navigation where we can specify this, possibly, at the composable level?

Answer (score 49):

You can get current activity from `LocalContext`, and then update [`requestedOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setRequestedOrientation(int)).

To set the desired orientation when the screen appears and bring it back when it disappears, use [`DisposableEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect):

```
@Composable
fun LockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(orientation) {
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    LockScreenOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DisposableEffect(orientation)`? So that the lambda is recomposed if the parameter changes?

Comment: Btw, this works also in the opposite direction: Most of my ui can only handle portrait mode, but for some i can allow landscape as an option using this with ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER

Comment: @m.reiter yeah, if you wanna make it dynamic, you should pass orientation as the key. it's just a wrapper, so it works same as `activity.requestedOrientation` in plain android. if you have to change orientation often in your app, you may need to write some more complex system, which will store stack of requested orientations, but this basic technique should work in most cases

Comment: Does the orientation change cause activity to reload and `onDispose` method to be called? I tried it to change orientation of WebView if user entered fullscreen mode and it immediately gets reverted to the `originalOrientation`

Comment: @Bresiu yes, `DisposableEffect` is getting reset on configuration change, you'll have to add more cumbersome logic

Comment: it works in simple case but it is not working in case of a navigation because it will restore the orientation of the previous screen before the new one has set the correct orientation.