# Android screen flickering in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

On drawing multiple `Box`es on top on each other, while keeping the screen in Landscape mode, the screen flickers and the orientation changes multiple times.

Here is a reproducible example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GamePad(widthDp: Float, heightDp: Float, connectionViewModel: ConnectionViewModel?) {
    LockScreenOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

    val deadZonePadding = heightDp / 18
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(deadZonePadding.dp)
//            .background(Color.Magenta)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart // Origin is top left
    ) {
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(deadZonePadding.dp)
//            .background(Color.Magenta)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart // Origin is bottom left
    ) {
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(deadZonePadding.dp)
//            .background(Color.Magenta)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd // Origin is top right
    ) {
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(deadZonePadding.dp)
//            .background(Color.Magenta)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd // Origin is bottom right
    ) {
    }

}
```

Supporting functions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231996/8659747

```kotlin
/**
 * Locks the screen orientation to the given orientation.
 * @see <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231996/8659747"> StackOverflow Answer <a/>
 */
@Composable
fun LockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(orientation) {
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```